# WebClient and VB.NET - Adding headers that have arrays

Tags: vb.net, webclient, request-headers

So I'm looking at something similar to this:

```
POST https://xxxx.io/testAPI
{
  "test": "string",
  "data": {
    "name": "",
    "description": "string",
  }
}
```

Adding general headers is fine:

```
NCLient3.QueryString.Add("test", "Test string")
```

But for data -> name and data -> description, how would I do it in this regard as it's an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, First, this is not a valid JSON.

```
{
"test": "string",
"data": {
"name": "",
"description": "string"
 }
}
```

You can get their values using Linq.

```
Dim json As String = "{'test': 'string','data': {'name': '','description': 'string'}}"
Dim jsn = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json)
Dim finalvalue As String = jsn.GetValue("data").Item("description").ToString()
```

and you'll get the value => string